# Column with render_* method in django-tables2 not working

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I have a table defined like this using `django-tables2`:

```
class MyTable(tables.Table):
    action = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['name', 'email']

    def render_action(self, record):
        return 'Foo'
```

But the `render_action` method is ignored and a -- is printed for every row instead. What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally solved it adding `empty_values=()` to the `action` column attributes.

Comment: This behaviour is documented here: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html?highlight=empty_values#django_tables2.columns.Column.render

Comment: I don't understand why the docs require this override, because my rows had data being rendered but it was ignored until I added `empty_values=()`. Does anyone have a better explanation?

Comment: The linked documentation states that if the attribute does not exists in the model, it is considered as a column with an empty value and it is not rendered.